# How to convert Array[String] into spark Dataframe to save CSV file format?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Code that I'm using to parse the CSV

```
val ListOfNames = List("Ramesh","Suresh","Ganesh") //Dynamical will add list of names
val Seperator = ListOfNames.map(x => x.split(",")  //mkString(",")

sc.parallelize(Array(seperator)).toDF().csv("path")
```

Getting output :

```
"Ramesh,Suresh,Ganesh" // Hence entire list into a single column in CSV
```

Expected output:

```
Ramesh, Suresh, Ganesh // each name into a single column in CSV
```

output should be in a row and each string should be in each column with comma separated.

If I try to change anything, it is saying CSV Data sources do not support array of string data type.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert your list of size n to a spark dataframe which holds n number of rows with only one column then the solution will look like below:

```
import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val listOfNames = List("Ramesh","Suresh","Ganesh")

val df = listOfNames.toDF("names")
df.show(false)
```

output:

```
+------+
|names |
+------+
|Ramesh|
|Suresh|
|Ganesh|
+------+
```

Comment: how to make row wise not column and each name should be in each column not Array[String]